# How to insert an image on a single_product page but not inside the related products

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce website and I was trying to insert an image element on a single product page which I already did using a conditional tag. But this single product page has related products included near the website footer which this same image is also inserting in each of them like in a loop which I do not want since it will load extra images and I do not want to hide them using CSS.

```
<?php

if ( is_product_tag() ) : ?>

<div class="security-badges">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/images/security-badges.png" alt="security-badges">
</div>

<?php endif ?>
```

So basically, I want to remove the images inside the Related Products loop on the same Single Product page. I'm not sure how to do this using conditional tags if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the right solution on a WooCommerce tutorial site.

```
<?php
// Add Securty Badges
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'security_badges', 20 );
function security_badges() {
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    $html = '';
    if ( is_product() && !$woocommerce_loop['name'] == 'related' ) {

        $html .='<div class="security-badges"><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/security-badges.png" alt="security-badges"></div>';
    }
    echo $html;
}
?>
```

And it does automatically appended next to the PayPal button on a Single Product page where I actually want.